# Ajax refresh for telerik radgrid

Tags: javascript, ajax, telerik, radgrid

I have a telerik radgrid along with several gridbound columns.  I want to reload the grid with the new data on a button click (which deletes one of the rows) without doing a posting back and refreshing the page.

But I am not sure how to use the telerik ajax manager, I have it as follow:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" >
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="myGrid">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="myGrid" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

then, I have a LinkButton when onclick it fires the `btn_OnCommand` on server side, which rebinds `myGrid` with the new retrieved data.  But I won't see the changes on client unless I refresh the page.  Could someone point me how to use the ajax manager?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the folllowing:

```
<telerik:ajaxsetting ajaxcontrolid="LinkButton1">  
    <updatedcontrols>  
        <telerik:ajaxupdatedcontrol controlid="RadGrid1"  />
    </updatedcontrols>  
</telerik:ajaxsetting>
```